# Stop propagating change to multiple instances of same object

Tags: javascript, css

I'm new to OOP in JS so I don't know why this is happening. When I change the color then click on my grid to add a different colored cell,  it changes the color for all the other cells to my current color. How do I make it where each cell can keep it's initial color?

This is the cell object and how it's color gets defined.

```
    function Cell(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.live = false;
        this.grid = grid;
        this.color = "#FF0000"; //default
        document.getElementById("color").addEventListener("input", function(){
            this.color = document.getElementById("color").value;
        }.bind(this)); // bind event callback to 'this'
    };
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fc8x6394/1/)

Comment: id's should be unique per element. you should select the element and pass it to the constructor.

Comment: It looks to me like every single `Cell` object is monitoring the central `<input>` element that holds the color value.  So, when you edit that field, then every single Cell updates its internal color since they all contain this same code that is monitoring the color value.  If you want only one cell to change, you'd have to have only one cell have an event listener to see modifications to the color `<input>` value that is being edited.

Comment: @jfriend00 where would I add an event listener for each cell? Would I do it when the object is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add an event listener for all cells so the callback will be fired for all cell objects when the color input changes.

Instead, you can do the following:

Remove addEventListener from the constructor

```
function Cell(x, y) {
  // var cell = this; // <==== no need to do this
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.live = false;
  this.grid = grid;
  this.color = "#FF0000"; //default
};
```

Then add a method to set the cell color based on the current input value

```
Cell.prototype.updateColor = function (){
  this.color = document.getElementById("color").value;
};
```

And call this method in the click event handler

```
td.addEventListener('click', (function (cell) {
  return function (e) {
    cell.toggle();
    cell.updateColor();
    viewModel.update();
  };
}(cell)));
```

See the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/332j4m9h/)

Comment: Ah. Thanks! I see what I was doing wrong. I wasn't doing the event listener for the instance of the individual objects.